# How can I tell when text is being typed into my Android SearchView on the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-menu, searchview, android-search

I want to disable certain features of my app while the user is entering text for a search.  The xml for the relevant item in my ActionBar is

```
<item android:id="@+id/actionbar_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/earth_2508858_search_en"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
```

and in the corresponding code that I have at present to cater for the search is

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);

    MenuItem DestinationTxt = menu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_search);
    final SearchView mySearchView = (SearchView)DestinationTxt.getActionView();     

    mySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { return false; }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Hide the Keyboard
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mySearchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
            // CODE TO DO THE SEARCH
            return true;
        }       
    });
}
```

I've browsed the methods on SearchView, but I didn't see anything that would tell me whether it's active or not.  I'm also worried about putting in a boolean state variable to indicate when the text is being typed into the SearchView, in case some behaviour that I haven't catered for occurs (e.g. back button pressed, activity gets suspended), and somehow the state variable gets stale so that the disabled features stay disabled.  So I'm looking for a robust way of doing this, all help appreciated :-).

**Update**.  An answer below suggests using the interface `OnFocusChangeListener` which is implemented by the mySearchView object, and/or the mySearchView.isFocussed() method.  Both sounded promising, however I've now tested and neither seem to work.  Perhaps their failure has got something to do with the fact that this SearchView is in the ActionBar?  In any case, I'm still after a robust solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since monitoring the focus didn't work, I looked at the SearchView documentation again. It's a bit convoluted, but it seems like the intended solution to this problem.

If your SearchView is inflated from a menu XML in onCreateOptionsMenu(), then you can add this line:

```
menu.findItem(/* your SearchView's ID here */).setOnActionExpandListener(
    new OnActionExpandListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse (MenuItem item){
            enableInteraction();
            return true; // Allow the SearchView to collapse.
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item){
            disableInteraction();
            return true; // Allow the SearchView to expand.
        }
    }
);
```

Then enable and disable your Activity's views in enableInteraction() and disableInteraction(), respectively. You should retain the MenuItem in your Activity so you can query it in onResume() like so:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    searchViewMenuItem.isActionViewExpanded() ? 
    disableInteraction() : enableInteraction();    
}
```

This part might not be needed. The SearchView might automatically get collapsed when the Activity is hidden and stay that way, so you can simply call enableInteraction() in onResume() so your user isn't locked out.

If you just need to reference the state of the SearchView, use

```
searchViewMenuItem.isActionViewExpanded();
```

Comment: I think I can just test menu.findItem(myid).isActionViewExpanded(), which would again make me happier because I don't need a state variable.

Comment: Yes, menu.findItem(myid).isActionViewExpanded() seems to work :-).  If you want to add that to your answer then I'll mark your answer as the Official Answer :-).

Comment: @Stochastically Where are you doing this? In onQueryTextChange()?

Comment: I want to disable behaviour elsewhere in my app when the user is entering text for search.  The MenuItem.isActionViewExpanded() method does seem to reflect that, so I have that MenuItem as an attribute of my activity and test it to see whether the behaviour should be active or not.  As I said, that does seem to work :-).

Answer (score 4):

It's right there.

```
mySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { return false; }
```

That's where you'll get updates to text changes in the SearchView.

The return value should be as such ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextChange%28java.lang.String%29)):

> Returns
>   false if the SearchView should perform the default action of showing any suggestions if available, true if the action was handled by the listener.

If you want to know if the SearchView has been activated or deactivated, use [View.setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29);

```
public interface OnFocusChangeListener{

    public void onFocusChange (View v, boolean hasFocus);
    // The boolean will tell you if it's focused or not.

}
```

Comment: Indeed, I want to disable something while it's in use which I guess means focussed, so OnFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange sounds promising but OnQueryTextListener.onQueryTextChange doesn't help me.  But to use OnFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange I need to set a state variable to record calls to that method, and as I said in the question I worry about state variables in case they get out of sync with what's actually happening.  Is there any way that focus could be lost (e.g. by the activity being paused when a phone call arrives), and OnFocusChangeListener not be called?

Comment: @Stochastically Check with [View.isFocused()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isFocused()) in onResume().

Comment: Thanks, pr perhaps I could just test (mySearchView.findFocus() == null) to determine whether the user is in text enter mode or not?  Just spotted your comment, I'll try View.isFocussed().  Perhaps if I call that I don't need a state variable at all, which makes me much happier :-).

Comment: @Stochastically That's one thing I noticed on Android. If you think you need a state variable, then you're not using the API to its full extent. Android will always have a way to get the information you need.

Comment: Curiously, neither of your very promising suggestions relating to focus worked.  I've updated the question with a comment at the bottom to this effect.

Comment: @Stochastically I'm looking at a separate solution now. Will add as a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've commented on your new answer

Comment: Calling setOnQueryTextListener let me get the String being entered in to the search view. Thanks